# Filter data based on last row mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by, having

I have this simple table setup [see fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/469b36/4)

```
    CREATE TABLE mytable
    (`id` int, `itemid` int);

    INSERT INTO mytable
    (`id`, `itemid`)
    VALUES
    (1, 111),
    (2, 222),
    (3, 333),
    (4, 444),
    (5, 111),
    (6, 222),
    (7, 333),
    (8, 564),
    (9, 111),
    (10, 121),
    (11, 131),
    (12, 111),
    (13, 353),
    (14, 373);
```

I want to show what the last itemid was in the row next to the current row itemid.
I have done that with the below

```
    SELECT 
    mt.id,
    mt.itemid,
    (
        select mt2.itemid
        from mytable mt2
        where mt2.id < mt.id
        ORDER BY mt2.id DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) as lastitemid
     FROM mytable mt 
     ORDER BY id DESC
     LIMIT 5
```

This works as expected returning

```
    ID  ITEMID  LASTITEMID
    14  373     353
    13  353     111
    12  111     131
    11  131     121
    10  121     111
```

However I only want to show rows where the lastitemid = 111 for example.

I have tried doing

```
    SELECT 
    mt.id,
    mt.itemid,
    (
        select mt2.itemid
        from mytable mt2
        where mt2.id < mt.id
        ORDER BY mt2.id DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) as lastitemid
    FROM mytable mt 
    WHERE lastitemid = 111
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 5
```

Which gets Unknown column 'lastitemid' in 'where clause'

I have also tried to add

```
    AND mt2.itemid = 111
```

To the inner query

This doesn't get any errors but returns 111 for all rows which is not what I want as it is invalid eg for id=12 the lastitemid is 131 but it says 111

```
    ID  ITEMID  LASTITEMID
    14  373     111
    13  353     111
    12  111     111
    11  131     111
    10  121     111
```

With my example data set I should get the below results if I had the query right

```
    ID  ITEMID  LASTITEMID
    13  353     111
    10  121     111
    6   222     111
    2   222     111
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Stab in the dark, but my first thought was somehow using GROUP BY?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT mt.id, mt.itemid,
      (SELECT mt2.itemid FROM mytable mt2 WHERE mt2.id < mt.id ORDER BY mt2.id DESC LIMIT 1) AS lastitemid
FROM mytable mt 
HAVING lastitemid = 111
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Check the [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/469b36/6)

**OUTPUT**

```
| ID | ITEMID | LASTITEMID |
|----|--------|------------|
| 13 |    353 |        111 |
| 10 |    121 |        111 |
|  6 |    222 |        111 |
|  2 |    222 |        111 |
```

Comment: Thanks I hadn't come accross HAVING before, it will come in handy for me!

Comment: This should actually work just as well with WHERE in place of HAVING.

Answer (score 1):

If the ids are guaranteed to be consecutive, you can do this.

```
SELECT curr.id, curr.itemid, previous.itemid AS lastitemid
FROM   mytable curr JOIN mytable previous ON previous.id = curr.id - 1
WHERE  previous.itemid = 111
```

Otherwise, you'd need something like

```
SELECT curr.id, curr.itemid, previous.itemid AS lastitemid
FROM   mytable curr, mytable previous
WHERE  previous.id < curr.id 
  AND  previous.itemid = 111
  AND NOT EXISTS ( 
      SELECT 1 FROM mytable interloper
      WHERE  interloper.id < curr.id
        AND  previous.id < interloper.id )
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the current query as a table, and then select from it with your where clause.

```
SELECT 
l.id,
l.itemid
FROM
(
    SELECT 
    mt.id,
    mt.itemid,
    (
        select mt2.itemid
        from mytable mt2
        where mt2.id < mt.id
        ORDER BY mt2.id DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) as lastitemid
    FROM mytable mt 
) As l
WHERE l.lastitemid = 111
ORDER BY l.id DESC
LIMIT 5
```